# Combine n number of dataframes on unique primary key pairs

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I currently have a dictionary of dataframes:

```
df_dict = {'apple': a_df, 'bees': b_df, 'food': c_df, 'yum': d_df}
```

Each dataframe has unique primary keys embedded in them
The primary key for each df created using: `df[p_k] = df[a] + df[b] + df[c]`

```
df_dict['apple']
a b c d p_k
9 5 3 4 953
3 6 4 9 364
7 6 5 1 765

df_dict['bees']
a b c d p_k
9 5 3 2 953

df_dict['food']
a b c d p_k
7 6 5 3 765
1 2 1 7 121

df_dict['yum']
a b c d p_k
3 6 4 0 364
1 2 1 8 121
```

The goal is to combine all dataframes on the p_k in a way that's computationally efficient (possible?).
Each p_k has **exactly** 1 matching pair in a different dataframe.
The matching p_k could be found in ANY of the dataframes in the dict.

The final goal of the above example would be to look like the following

```
final_df
a b c d d_y p_k
9 5 3 4  2  953
3 6 4 9  0  364
1 2 1 7  8  121
7 6 5 1  3  765
```

I have a basic understanding of the .merge function but am looking for an efficient way to search as the real problem has a dict with 30 dataframes with 70 rows per.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to keep the first occurring row when merging two dataframes? If that's the case, you could use `functools.reduce` on the dataframe values each time concatenating two of them and dropping duplicates using `drop_duplicates`(it keeps the first value by default keep='first')

Now you also want to retain `d` column. For that what you could do is reduce again but this time drop_duplicates based on all columns except `d` which in this case dropping on `p_k` is enough and keeping the last value.

And then merge these two reduced dataframes. The code looks like:

```
from functools import reduce
df1 = reduce(
    lambda df1, df2: pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates("p_k"),
    df_dict.values(),
)
df2 = reduce(
    lambda df1, df2: pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(
        "p_k", keep="last", ignore_index=True
    ),
    df_dict.values(),
)
out = df1.merge(df2, on=["a", "b", "c", "p_k"], suffixes=("", "_y"))
print(out)

   a  b  c  d  p_k  d_y
0  9  5  3  4  953    2
1  3  6  4  9  364    0
2  7  6  5  1  765    3
3  1  2  1  7  121    8
```

Comment: You're missing the d_y column.  I try this way first also.

Comment: @ScottBoston Fixed the answer to get the d_y column too.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
dc=pd.concat([d.set_index('p_k') for d in df_dict.values()])
dc_out=dc.assign(grp=dc.groupby(['p_k', 'a', 'b', 'c'])['d'].cumcount())\
         .set_index(['a', 'b','c', 'grp'], append=True)\
         .unstack('grp')

dc_out.columns = [f'{i}_y' if j==1 else f'{i}' for i, j in dc_out.columns]
df_out = dc_out.reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   p_k  a  b  c  d  d_y
0  121  1  2  1  7    8
1  364  3  6  4  9    0
2  765  7  6  5  1    3
3  953  9  5  3  4    2
```